# how to change the default height of the edittext to small?

Tags: android, resize, android-edittext

I am using Edittext in my application but want to resize it please tell me how to do it?

```
    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:singleLine="true"/>
```

[image: This is one of my actitivity i want to resize my all edit text]

Comment: resize means what ? what is the actual requirement ? make it clear.

Comment: why you want to resize, you can add as character as you want then

Comment: this is my edittext code
<EditText
     android:layout_width="200dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:singleLine="true"/>
but as i am using many edittext in my activity i want their size to be small, so want to resize it!

Answer (score 2):

**To get smaller edittext use smaller dip values in `android:layout_width`**

```
android:layout_width="200dip"   EditText with bigger width
android:layout_width="150dip"   EditText with smaller width than above
android:layout_width="100dip"   EditText with smaller width than above
android:layout_width="50dip"   EditText with smaller width than above
...
..
android:layout_width="0dip"   EditText with width 0 you cant see this edittext
```

**set the EditText width to appropriate size which you want to set**

Comment: @Down voters. Please Make some efforts to mention the reason behind downvoting, which will help other developers to know the exact reason behind down voting. Dont hide your self and the reason.

Comment: - Sir, i want to change the default height of the edittext to small and not its width!!!

Comment: similar thing you can do to set EditText Height by setting value for android:layout_height="50dip" and so on

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"/>
```

Replace "20" with the size you want. Higher number = bigger